# HTML Marquee - Static text

Tags: html, css, marquee

I am wondering if a HTML marquee allows static text at the start of the control (or container) so when the text slides to the left it will slide pass the text?

For example.

I am looking at the the date to be static aligned to the left and the text from the database will slide pass it and then reappear from the right.

**HTML:**

```
 <marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" 
    class="html-scroller" direction="left" behavior="scroll" scrollamount="12">
   <p style="color:#626060; font-weight:bold">24/05/2015 - Some Infor here</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.html-scroller 
{
    height:30px;
    border:solid;
}
```

Of course, the code above will make the text including the date slide pass the edge on the controller.

Looking at marquee examples there isn't anything, so if I have to change it, would be be easier to create my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a partial static text solution for marquees.
I'd do this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="date">24/05/2015</div>
  <div>
    <marquee
      onmouseover="this.stop();"
      onmouseout="this.start();"
      direction="left"
      behavior="scroll"
      scrollamount="12">
      <p>
        Some Infor here
      </p>
    </marquee>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container
{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #626060;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container,
.container .date {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #626060;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container .date {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

.container marquee {
    line-height: 0.8;
}

.container marquee p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1wzxywtn/